# Python - append to list of dicts while keeping order

Tags: python

I have a python list that contains dicts of personal information like so:

```
entries = [
    {
        "first_name": "philip",
        "last_name": "fry"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "john",
        "last_name": "zoidberg"
    }
]
```

I would like to add entries to this list, in such as way that ascending (last name, first name) order is maintained. The bisect module looks promising, but it does not seem to support this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The `blist` package provides a `sortedlist` type that may be useful.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how performant you need it to be, you can just resort after each addition. Something like (untested code):

```
def add(item, aList):
    aList.append(item)
    return sorted(aList, key=lambda entry:"{}{}".format(entry['last_name'], entry['first_name'])
```

It's not efficient, but if you have the flexibility, it's simple.

Answer (score 2):

If the list is homogeneous, i.e. all entries are a pair of names, you could use tuples instead of dicts since the keys don't add much value in this case.

And if you kept the tuples in last name, first name order you could use bisect:

```
In [1]: entries = [("fry", "philip"), ("zoidberg", "john")]

In [2]: entries.sort()

In [3]: entries
Out[3]: [('fry', 'philip'), ('zoidberg', 'john')]

In [4]: import bisect

In [5]: bisect.insort(entries, ("turanga", "leela"))

In [6]: entries
Out[6]: [('fry', 'philip'), ('turanga', 'leela'), ('zoidberg', 'john')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right in thinking the `bisect` module would do what you need, and it is quite efficient. As it does not have a `key` function, you simply build your own key list prior to calling it. It will then return the correct insert point for you to use in your list:

```
import bisect

entries = [
    {"first_name": "philip", "last_name": "fry"},
    {"first_name": "john", "last_name": "zoidberg"}]

new_entry = {'first_name': 'anne', 'last_name': 'bedford'}

keys = [(d['last_name'], d['first_name']) for d in entries]
entries.insert(bisect.bisect_left(keys, (new_entry['last_name'], new_entry['first_name'])), new_entry)
print entries
```

This would give you the following output:

```
[{'first_name': 'anne', 'last_name': 'bedford'}, {'first_name': 'philip', 'last_name': 'fry'}, {'first_name': 'john', 'last_name': 'zoidberg'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

A less simple but more efficient approach is to use the `sortedcontainers` module (which uses `bisect` as you suspected).

You have to extend `dict` to make it sortable.

```
class Person(dict):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return '{}{}'.format(self['last_name'], self['first_name']) <
               '{}{}'.format(other['last_name'], other['first_name'])
```

Then add `Person` objects to a sorted list:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedList
sorted_list = SortedList()
p = Person()
p['first_name'] = 'philip'
p['last_name']  = 'fry'
sorted_list.append(p)
```

Comment: You can actually just use `sortedcontainers.SortedListWithKey` and make the key function: `lambda value: (value['last_name'], value['first_name'])`